# What happens to the target of Oko, Thief of Crowns' second ability when it is put in the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

An artifact or creature becomes a 3/3 green Elk creature due to [Oko, Thief of Crowns](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bOko%2c%20Thief%20of%20Crowns%5d)' second ability. What happens to that artifact or creature when it is put into the graveyard? Does it remain a 3/3 green Elk creature? Or does it revert back to it's original state once in the graveyard?

For example, [Death's Shadow](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDeath%27s%5d%2b%5bShadow%5d) is turned into a 3/3 green Elk creature. For the purposes of using [Unearth](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=464062), when in the graveyard does it remain as a 3/3 green Elk creature, or does it revert back to being 'Death's Shadow'?

Answer (score 4):

It will become a Death's Shadow again. Whenever an object changes zones, e.g. when it goes from the battlefield to the graveyard, it gets completely 'reset':

> 400.7. An object that moves from one zone to another becomes a new object with no memory of, or relation to, its previous existence.

The rules list nine exceptions to this, but your situation is not one of them.